# Proof on the order of conditions in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

> Suppose $f(x)$ suffices to the following expression: 
>   $(\forall a\in D)(\exists\delta\gt0)(\forall\epsilon\gt0)(\forall x\in D)(|x-a|\lt\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|\lt\epsilon)$
>
> Proof that the above expression isn't the same as $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition for continuity.

On one hand one can start by looking for a counterexample which is a continuous function that doesn't suffice the condition and on the other hand you can look for a discontinuous function for which the expression holds.

For the $2^{nd}$ case I would use the stepfunction at a certain point a for which it intuitively holds. But I can't find a counterexample that contradicts the above expression.

Any hints?

Comment: the difference between arguments is less than $\delta$ and two function values is less than $\varepsilon$, I presume. If not then the implication is trivially true.

Comment: @AlvinLepik What do you mean? Should I take the difference of two elementary functions?

Comment: You have quantified some epsilons and deltas, but never use them in the implication.

Comment: I think there might be a few typos in your question: $|x-a|<0,\ |f(x)-f(a)|<0$ don't make sense.

Comment: Yeah I'll edit that

Comment: @EdMo38 Now it should be correct.

Comment: Is this an exercise in elementary calculus or elementary mathematical logic? The emphasis on quantifiers in the definition of limit is highly misplaced. Consider the following fact: for every positive integer $n>1$ there is a prime $p$ such that $p$ divides $n$. I have never seen this written using quantifiers. The real challenge in limit definition is the statement after the quantifiers and not the quantifiers themselves.

Comment: It is used in calculus the first year of university in the introductory chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of continuity for $f:D\to\mathbb R,D\subseteq\mathbb R$

> $$(\forall a\in D)(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists\delta >0)(\forall x\in D)\left (|x-a|<\delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon\right )$$

The condition you gave is:

> $$(\forall a\in D)(\exists\delta\gt0)(\forall\epsilon\gt0)(\forall x\in D)(|x-a|\lt\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(a)|\lt\epsilon) $$

But now we must have a $\delta$ that is universal for every $\varepsilon$ opposed to finding a $\delta = \delta (\varepsilon)$.
Switching the order of the quantifiers changes the expression.

For a counter-example you may consider $f(x) = x$. Fix $a\in\mathbb R$. Does there exist a $\delta$ such that the difference between any $f(x)$ and $f(a)$, where $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$, is arbitrarily small?

Suppose such a $\delta >0 $ exists. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{\delta}{2}$. Then for $x = a+\delta /2\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ and $$|f(x)-f(a)|\geq \varepsilon\ $$

Comment: So if you choose $x,y$ arbitrarily into the interval $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$ you can get a $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ in the interval $f(a)-\epsilon, f(a)+\epsilon$. I think it is wrong because you said it is an counterexample but if I draw what you said I can find the $\epsilon$. Sorry for my stupid remark but I really don't understand why it's a counterexample.

Comment: .. but can you ? There is only function that satisfies this demand, therefore the other functions suffice as counter-examples

Comment: I've made a graph and drawn it on there. So yes.

Comment: I have edited the post to illustrate why it's a counterexample.

Comment: So because $\frac {\delta}{2} \lt\delta$ (strictly less) $\Rightarrow$ there is no such value for which an $\epsilon$ exists.

Comment: We have specified a point in the neighborhood of $a$ which fails to satisfy $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Also, I corrected a mistake: we have $a$ fixed, so we only choose $x$ freely around $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in D=\Bbb R .$ Take some $\delta >0$ such that the rest of the expression is satisfied . Then for any $x\in (-\delta+a,+\delta+a)$ we have $$\forall \epsilon >0\;(|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon)$$ which implies that  $f(x)=f(a)$  for every $x\in (-\delta+a,+\delta+a).$

BTW. In the case $D=\Bbb R$ this will also imply that $f$ is constant, i.e. $\forall x\;(f(x)=f(0)\;)$.